# Java connection with BaseX error: Connection refused: no further information

Tags: java, xml, xpath, basex

I am trying to run the following code:

```
package practicaXML;
import javax.xml.xquery.*;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import net.xqj.basex.BaseXXQDataSource;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            XQDataSource xqs = new BaseXXQDataSource();
            xqs.setProperty("serverName", "localhost");
            xqs.setProperty("port", "1984");
            xqs.setProperty("databaseName", "facts");
            XQConnection conn = xqs.getConnection("admin", "admin");

            String xqueryString = "//province[contains(@name, 'x')]";
            XQExpression xqe = conn.createExpression();
            XQResultSequence rs = xqe.executeQuery(xqueryString);

            Node n;
            while(rs.next()) {
                n = rs.getNode();
                System.out.println(n.getAttributes().getNamedItem("name").getNodeValue());
            }

            conn.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

And I get this error:

```
Error: Connection refused: no further information
```

It is my first time working with BaseX and I haven't changed any credential, so all the values should be on default. What could be causing it?

Also, I assume admin admin are the default credentials, please correct me if I'm worng. And are there any details that I should keep in mind? For instance, do I need to close BaseX while I'm trying to make the connection?